# A number that is even and prime.

Tags: predicate-logic

So I have the following sentence : There exists a unique prime number that is even.

I have the following predicates :

Prim(x) : x is a prime number.
Even(x) : x is an even number.

My answer : Prim(Even(x))

I don't know, but I think that this would be better : Ǝ Prim(Even(x))

Would this make sense ? Even though we know that there is only one such number that is prime and even.

Thank yoU!

Comment: The expression "Prim(Even(x))" is not well-formed: it's basically saying "'$x$ is even' is prime."

Comment: You need to say that there exists a number that is both even and prime (existence), and any number that is both even and prime is equal to that number (uniqueness).  Can you see how to formalize that?

Comment: Yeah, so I would get this : Prim(x) ∧ Even(x) But How do I know that there aren't more than one ? How do I make sure that this represents only one particular number ?

Comment: Hint: for any $y$ with the same property follows $y=\dotsc$ ?

Comment: Sorry user, I didn't see this type of stuff. I only know the really basic stuff about it... I'm not sure how to make Prim(x) ∧ Even(x) unique....

Comment: @Astroman unique (or more precisely at most one) means, if $x$ and $y$ are even and prime, it follows $x=y$

Comment: Prim(x) ∧ Even(x) --> Equal(x,2) DOes this make sense ? To be honest, I have no idea....

Answer (score 4):

"There is exactly one even prime number" can be expressed formally as
$$ \exists x: [(Even(x) \land Prim(x)) \land \forall y : [Even(y) \land Prim(y) \implies x=y]]. $$
The first part says there is *at least* one even prime number. The second part says there is *at most* one even prime number.

Answer (score -2):

For the statement "There exists a unique Prime number that is Even."
it's rather more simple.

$\exists  x: [\operatorname{Even}(x)\land\operatorname{Prim}(x)]$

My explanation for this is that the existential quantifier $\exists x$  means:-

1. There exists an 'x'
2. For some 'x'
3. For at least one 'x'

Here it is used to reference that "there exists a unique 'x' satisfying both $\operatorname{Even}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Prim}(x)$".

Comment: Please edit your answer using mathjax

Comment: Write \$\forall x \$ surounded with dollars to render the math

Comment: As you say, $\exists$ means "at least one" -- your statement does *not* assert uniqueness.

Comment: Saying that there exists some value $x$ satisfying some condition does not imply that that is the only value satisfying that condition.